# Error with cssparser-0.9.5.jar in Netbeans using richfaces/JSF

Tags: jsf, netbeans, richfaces

For some reason when I make minor chances to the title or anything linked to css I get the following error:

Deleting directory C:\Users...
C:\Users...\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1057: Unable to delete file
C:\Users...\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\cssparser-0.9.5.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)

Line 1057: `<delete dir="${build.dir}"/>`

I undid the changes but the error seems to persist.
Why would it want to delete the cssparser jar file?
What's the solution to the problem.

I am using Richfaces in JSF using Netbeans as my IDE, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NetBeans does a Clean to the project, that means NetBeans will try to delete the compiled files and any libraries it has copied into the deploy directory. In Windows, NetBeans can't find the deploy dir and shows this error, specially when this dir is inside *My Documents*. I recommend you to change your project directory, or just performing **Run** or **Debug**, these commands will Compile, Build, Deploy and Launch your application so there won't be the Clean error.

For more info, see http://forums.netbeans.org/topic39444.html

Comment: Thank you. This may seem like an obvious question but how would changing the directory resolve the issue?

Comment: @Infinity when you're in Windows and create the project in the default Netbeans folder, you can access directly there with an explorer, but the deploy folders are used for the glassfish application server, so these files can't be deleted for being used by another process. This issue is known for Windows only, like the forum link says.